# Search, replace and highlighting String in Swift 2.0

Tags: ios, swift2

I want to search for specific string and replace it with same string without changing the case.

Lets us say I have the following string -  'Good Morning. This is too good.', I want to search for 'good' and highlight it with different color, but I have maintain same case.

I tried with 'stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString()', but the problem here is it replaces 'Good' with 'good', but I need to maintain the case of String.

How can this be achieved?

Comment: What are you replacing Occurrences with ?

Comment: `but the problem here is it replaces 'Good' with 'good'` Wrong, try again. `.stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString("good", withString: "test")` only replaces "good", not "Good".

Answer (score 0):

1. Lowercase a copy of the string ie 'Good Morning...'
2. Iterate through the string looking for key words ie 'good'
3. When found, record their index and length in a separate array.
4. Go to the original string and update their colour.